# Whitebox Packages and image in html files

Tags: html, package

I'm trying to embed images in the different htmls (intro, readme, etc...) but the images never show up in the final build. Is there something particular to take care of, or maybe it's simply not possible?

Please see
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bC19.png)

Thanks, Greg

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show us a sample of the issue?  And the results of that sample code?

Comment: Sure! Thank you!